# variance used in multivariate normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, variance

[image]

Click on image twice to make it large.

This is taken from the Ross probability book. Can someone derive how they obtain

$$Var(X_i)=\sum^{n}_{j=1}a_{ij}^2$$

Comment: It is well known that if $X_i$ are independent standard normal variables then $\sum_{i=1}^na_iX_i$ is also normally distributed with mean zero and variance $\sum_i{a_i^2}$. The proof involves evaluating integrals on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Do you have a link or a reference to a proof?

Comment: Yes. Google "Variance of linear combination of independent Gaussians"

Comment: thanks for the answer!